# “field-with-errors” wrapper changes the page appearance with <pre> tag in ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image]

I am using `<div class="field_with_errors">` to show validation errors with twitter bootstrap. But when validation error appears, these create extra space between controls that cause whole UI gets broken as you can see from image. How to avoid this extra space. Second thing that I want to display validation errors in front of controls not below. How it would be possible. When I tried to debug this css using Firbug, I got to know there is `<pre> </pre>` HTML tae and they causing this extra space. I have put red color for extra space in image.

Please suggest me how to avoid this extra space and get validation errors on right side of controls (infront). Please let me know if you need more code to be pasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Rails is going to inject a block element into your form. This is where

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
```

comes from. To avoid the extra space you need to have Rails inject an inline element, such as a span. To do this go into `config/application.rb` include this:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
      "<span class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</span>".html_safe
    end

  end
end
```

This configuration gives Rails a Proc function to call that will now generate your form error elements. You can alter this html to your pleasing. You can find more information here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-view